# How to fill ckeditor from capybara with webkit or selenium driver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, webkit, ckeditor, capybara

How can I fill a CKEditor area within Capybara, assuming I'm using a javascript capable driver like capybara-webkit or selenium?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Inspired from what I found [here](http://saratrice.com/2011/03/09/testing-ckeditor-in-ruby-on-rails-with-cucumbercapybara/), I came up with the solution of using javascript to both set the data on the hidden `textarea` and on the `CKEditor` object. Neither seemed sufficient, depending on the circumstances.

```
def fill_in_ckeditor(locator, opts)
  content = opts.fetch(:with).to_json # convert to a safe javascript string
  page.execute_script <<-SCRIPT
    CKEDITOR.instances['#{locator}'].setData(#{content});
    $('textarea##{locator}').text(#{content});
  SCRIPT
end

# Example:
fill_in_ckeditor 'email_body', :with => 'This is my message!'
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it really saved me a ton of time. One small correction: in capybara 2.1.0, `browser.execute_script` above should be `page.execute_script`.

Comment: great method here.  worked like a charm...just copy and paste.

Comment: `locator` must be text area ID :)

Comment: Why `to_json` ?

Comment: `to_json` is an easy way to properly escape javascript content. If `content` contains a single or double quote, for example...

Comment: I spent a few hours trying to do this using JS until I came upon your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

A small addition to [Marc-André's awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10957870/518204)

If you are using nested form or multiple textareas in the same page generated IDs are pretty ugly and hard to write into tests (e.g. `person_translations_attributes_2_biography`) with this small addition to his method you can locate ckeditors using their labels instead of ID

```
# Used to fill ckeditor fields
# @param [String] locator label text for the textarea or textarea id
def fill_in_ckeditor(locator, params = {})
  # Find out ckeditor id at runtime using its label
  locator = find('label', text: locator)[:for] if page.has_css?('label', text: locator)
  # Fill the editor content
  page.execute_script <<-SCRIPT
      var ckeditor = CKEDITOR.instances.#{locator}
      ckeditor.setData('#{params[:with]}')
      ckeditor.focus()
      ckeditor.updateElement()
  SCRIPT
end
```

In this way instead of this

```
fill_in_ckeditor 'person_translations_attributes_2_biography', with: 'Some text'
```

you can write this

```
fill_in_ckeditor 'Biography', with: 'Some text'
```

Comment: I was just about to write something exactly like this when I read Marc-André's answer.  I'm glad I kept reading.  Thank you!

Comment: if you use ckeditor.updateElement() to set the value of the hidden textarea element (instead of setting it directly with jquery, like in Marc-André's answer) you might experience random failing tests, when capybara isn't waiting on your js to finish executing.

when you add 

page.should have_field(locator, with: params[:with], visible: false)

capybara waits until the hidden text element has the expected value.

Answer (score 3):

For me [Marc-André's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957869/how-to-fill-ckeditor-from-capybara-with-webkit-or-selenium-driver/10957870#10957870) switches iframe context in webkit driver. See [this capybara-webkit issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/620)

I found another way to fill in ckeditor input which doesn't change iframe context:

```
  def fill_in_ckeditor(id, with:)
    within_frame find("#cke_#{id} iframe") do
      find('body').base.send_keys with
    end
  end
```

and call it

`fill_in_ckeditor 'comment', with: 'This is my message!'`

Works both with webkit and selenium drivers

Inspired by [this post](https://medium.com/@jeffreyqua/capybara-and-div-contenteditable-ef3fe07de765)

Answer (score 2):

RSpec + Capybara support file to work with ckeditor instances

```
module Ckeditor
  class Instance
    attr_reader :capybara
    private :capybara

    def initialize(instance_id, capybara)
      @instance_id, @capybara = instance_id, capybara
    end

    def val(value)
      capybara.execute_script "jQuery('textarea##{@instance_id}').val('#{value}')"
    end

    def reload_all
      capybara.execute_script "for(var instance in CKEDITOR.instances) { if(CKEDITOR.instances.hasOwnProperty(instance)) {CKEDITOR.instances[instance].destroy(true);} }"
      capybara.execute_script "CKEDITOR.replaceAll();"
    end
  end
end

# usage
# rte = Ckeditor::Instance.new(:my_instance_id, page)
# rte.val 'foo'
# rte.reload_all
# NOTE: page is provided by Capybara
```

https://gist.github.com/3308129