# Rspec not accessing datas updated via capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a form containing a "name" regular input field and a "content" CKeditor textarea. As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957869/how-to-fill-ckeditor-from-capybara-with-webkit-or-selenium-driver) I can fill in the form and if I stop here I can see the "name" and "content" columns correctly updated in the Test DataBase. Fine.

Now, if I do :

```
template = ContractTemplate.all.last   
puts "#{template.name}" # => "template_name"
puts "#{template.content}" # => "<p>template_content</p>"
```

And then problem begins, if I try to update those two attributes (still using Capybara), I now always fall back on values saved at the "create" action, although they ARE correctly updated into the database. It's just like there where no update of the values. I've tried to do ContractTemplate.reload , but it doesn't work.

Full spec is like this :

```
it 'should edit a contract template', :js => true do

  visit contract_templates_path
  click_link "Add"

  fill_in "contract_template_name", :with => "test_template_name"
  fill_in_ckeditor "contract_template_content", :with => "test_template_content"
  click_button "Save"

  template = ContractTemplate.all.last
  template.name.should eq("test_template_name") # pass, content created
  template.content.should eq("<p>\r\n\ttest_template_content</p>\r\n") # pass

  visit contract_template_path(template.id)

  fill_in "contract_template_name", :with => "edited_test_template_name"
  fill_in_ckeditor "contract_template_content", :with => "edited_test_template_content"
  click_button "Save"

  template.name.should eq("edited_test_template_name") # Fail, because == "test_template_name"
  template.content.should eq("<p>\r\n\tedited_test_template_content</p>\r\n") # Fail, not updated too

end
```

My approach may be wrong, but since the "content" attribute is filled using a wisiwig editor, I just can't see any other way to test if the save action really updates name and content... BTW there is no view in the app where I could display the result of the textarea, it's all going to be rendered as PDF.

Could someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `template.reload` after your second save. Otherwise, the `template` record will  contain the values from when it was first loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I GOT IT ! I just had to turn transactionnal fixtures to false inside spec_helper.rb :

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false # true by default
  ...
end
```

Now everything runs fine. Ho my... 4 hours on this, I was just getting mad.